# Python Hangman incorrect guesses

Tags: python, list, append, addition

I have a hangman code. Its pretty long, and you don't have to read it all(but if you're willing to, go ahead):

```
import random

import sys

from string import whitespace


guess = ''

guess2 = 0

guess3 = 0

guess4 = 0

guess5 = 0

guess6 = 0

guess7 = 0

guess8 = 0

guess9 = 0

guess10 = 0

guess11 = 0

guess12 = 0

guess13 = 0

guess14 = 0

guess15 = 0

guess16 = 0

guess17 = 0

guess18 = 0

guess19 = 0

guess20 = 0

guess21 = 0



lis = [ ]



uy = 'jrekghqegherwgbeuihrweig'

choice = 'bhekvvvvvfaktgrwekubfhdbvbvdvbd'

z = 'bqhjrfqfbrqkqbg'

s = 'ksl'

s_space = 'bhks'

li = [ ]

a1a = None

a2a = None

a3a = None

a4a = None

a5a = None

a6a = None

a7a = None

a8a = None

a9a = None

a10a = None

a11a = None

a12a = None 

a13a = None

a14a = None

a15a = None

a16a = None

a17a = None

t = list(s)

googe = r'''

    /@
    \ \ 
  ___> \ 
 (__O)  \ 
(____@)  \
(____@)   \
(__o)_     \
       \    \
'''


comps = r'''

   ._________________.
   |.---------------.|
   ||    hangman    ||
   ||   -._ .-.     ||
   ||   -._| | |    ||
   ||   -._|"|"|    ||
   ||   -._|.-.|    ||
   ||_______________||
   /.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.\
  /.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.\
 /.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.\
/______/__________\_____\     
\_______________________/

'''



hangman = """
 +---+
 |   |
     |
     |
     |
     |
 =========
"""

hangman1 = """
 +---+
 |   |
 O   |
     |
     |
     |
 =========
"""

hangman2 = """
 +---+
 |   |
 O   |
 |   |
     |
     |
 =========
"""

hangman3 = """
 +---+
 |   |
 O   |
 |/  |
     |
     |
 =========
"""

hangman4 = """
 +---+
 |   |
 O   |
\|/  |
     |
     |
 =========
"""

hangman5 = """
 +---+
 |   |
 O   |
\|/  |
 |   |
     |
 =========
"""

hangman6 = """
 +---+
 |   |
 O   |
\|/  |
 |   |
  \  |
 =========
"""

hangman7 = """
 +---+
 |   |
 O   |
\|/  |
 |   |
/ \  |
 =========

Game Over.
"""

hangman0 = hangman


animals = [ 'Swan']

space = ['astronomy', 'gas', 'nebula', 'planet', 'Earth', 'sun', 'space', 'star', 'Venus', 'Mars', 'Mercury', 'Pluto', 'Neptune', 'Uranus', 'ice', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn', 'asteroid', 'comet', 'Kepler', 'ISS', 'station', 'quasar', 'galaxy', 'Andromeda', 'moon', 'Phobios', 'Demios', 'orbit', 'gravity', 'matter']

food = ['pizza', 'bagel', 'donut', 'candy', 'cake', 'casserole', 'salmon', 'bacon', 'caviar', 'apple', 'bannana', 'orange', 'acai', 'pomegranete', 'pear', 'cheese', 'turkey', 'steak', 'Cabbage', 'Calorie', 'Carbohydrate', 'Casserole', 'Caterer', 'Celery', 'Chef', 'Chewy', 'Chicken', 'Chicory', 'Chipotle', 'Chips', 'Chocolate', 'Chocolatier', 'Choice', 'Chutney', 'Cocoa', 'Coffee', 'Condiment', 'mango', 'Crackers', 'Croutons', 'Crunchy', 'Cucumbers', 'potato', 'sandwich']

chemicals = ['alum', 'sodium', 'titin', 'Bichrome', 'Azurite', 'Borax', 'Calomel', 'Gypsum', 'graphite', 'hypo', 'lime', 'acetone', 'pollen', 'Aluminium', 'starch', 'soap', 'calcium', 'alchohol', 'seltzer', 'aspirin', 'bronze', 'chalk', 'diamond', 'marble', 'quartz', 'sand', 'silicon', 'vinegar', 'carbon', 'nitrogen', 'vapor', 'oxide', 'phosphorus', 'magnesium', 'acid', 'chemical', 'ackey']



print 'Welcome to hangman!'

import time
time.sleep(3)
print 'Pick a topic:'
print '1.Animals'
print '2.Space'
print '3.Food'
print '4.Chemicals'

topic = str(raw_input('Choose a topic(1/2/3/4):'))

if not topic.isalpha():
    if topic == '1':
        choice = animals
        print 'animals'
    elif topic == '2':
        choice = space
        print 'space'
    elif topic == '3':
        choice = food
        print 'food'
    elif topic == '4':
        choice = chemicals
        print 'chemicals'
    else:
        print 'Invalid Input'
        topic = str(raw_input('Choose a topic(1/2/3/4):'))
elif topic != '1' or '2' or '3' or '4':
    print 'Invalid Input'
    topic = str(raw_input('Choose a topic(1/2/3/4):'))




if choice == animals:
    word = random.choice(animals)

if choice == food:
    word = random.choice(food)

if choice == space:
    word = random.choice(space)

if choice == chemicals:
    word = random.choice(chemicals)

word = word.lower()
length = len(word)

if length == 3:
    s = '_ _ _'
    a1a = word[0]
    a2a = word[1]
    a3a = word[2]
    lis = [a1a, a2a, a3a]

if length == 4:
    s = '_ _ _ _'
    a1a = word[0]
    a2a = word[1]
    a3a = word[2]
    a4a = word[3]
    lis = [a1a, a2a, a3a, a4a]

if length == 5:
    s = '_ _ _ _ _' 
    a1a = word[0]
    a2a = word[1]
    a3a = word[2]
    a4a = word[3]
    a5a = word[4]
    lis = [a1a, a2a, a3a, a4a, a5a]

if length == 6:
    s = '_ _ _ _ _ _' 
    a1a = word[0]
    a2a = word[1]
    a3a = word[2]
    a4a = word[3]
    a5a = word[4]
    a6a = word[5]
    lis = [a1a, a2a, a3a, a4a, a5a, a6a]

if length == 7:
    s = '_ _ _ _ _ _ _'
    a1a = word[0]
    a2a = word[1]
    a3a = word[2]
    a4a = word[3]
    a5a = word[4]
    a6a = word[5]
    a7a = word[6]
    list = [a1a, a2a, a3a, a4a, a5a, a6a, a7a]

if length == 8:
    s = '_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _'
    a1a = word[0]
    a2a = word[1]
    a3a = word[2]
    a4a = word[3]
    a5a = word[4]
    a6a = word[5]
    a7a = word[6]
    a8a = word[7]
    lis = [a1a, a2a, a3a, a4a, a5a, a6a, a7a, a8a]

if length == 9:
    s = '_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _'
    a1a = word[0]
    a2a = word[1]
    a3a = word[2]
    a4a = word[3]
    a5a = word[4]
    a6a = word[5]
    a7a = word[6]
    a8a = word[7]
    a9a = word[8]
    lis = [a1a, a2a, a3a, a4a, a5a, a6a, a7a, a8a, a9a]

if length == 10:
    s = '_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _'
    a1a = word[0]
    a2a = word[1]
    a3a = word[2]
    a4a = word[3]
    a5a = word[4]
    a6a = word[5]
    a7a = word[6]
    a8a = word[7]
    a9a = word[8]
    a10a = word[9]
    lis = [a1a, a2a, a3a, a4a, a5a, a6a, a7a, a8a, a9a, a10a]

if length == 11:
    s = '_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _'
    a1a = word[0]
    a2a = word[1]
    a3a = word[2]
    a4a = word[3]
    a5a = word[4]
    a6a = word[5]
    a7a = word[6]
    a8a = word[7]
    a9a= word[8]
    a10a = word[9]
    a11a = word[10]
    lis = [a1a, a2a, a3a, a4a, a5a, a6a, a7a, a8a, a9a, a10a, a11a]

if length == 12:
    s = '_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _'
    a1a = word[0]
    a2a = word[1]
    a3a = word[2]
    a4a = word[3]
    a5a = word[4]
    a6a = word[5]
    a7a = word[6]
    a8a = word[7]
    a9a = word[8]
    a10a = word[9]
    a11a = word[10]
    a12a = word[11]
    lis = [a1a, a2a, a3a, a4a, a5a, a6a, a7a, a8a, a9a, a10a, a11a, a12a]

if length == 13:
    s = '_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _'
    a1a = word[0]
    a2a = word[1]
    a3a = word[2]
    a4a = word[3]
    a5a = word[4]
    a6a = word[5]
    a7a = word[6]
    a8a = word[7]
    a9a = word[8]
    a10a = word[9]
    a11a = word[10]
    a12a = word[11]
    a13a = word[12]
    lis = [a1a, a2a, a3a, a4a, a5a, a6a, a7a, a8a, a9a, a10a, a11a, a12a, a13a]

if length == 14:
    s = '_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _'
    a1a = word[0]
    a2a = word[1]
    a3a = word[2]
    a4a = word[3]
    a5a = word[4]
    a6a = word[5]
    a7a = word[6]
    a8a= word[7]
    a9a= word[8]
    a10a = word[9]
    a11a = word[10]
    a12a = word[11]
    a13a = word[12]
    a14a = word[13]
    lis = [a1a, a2a, a3a, a4a, a5a, a6a, a7a, a8a, a9a, a10a, a11a, a12a, a13a, a14a]

if length == 15:
    s = '_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _'
    a1a = word[0]
    a2a = word[1]
    a3a = word[2]
    a4a = word[3]
    a5a = word[4]
    a6a = word[5]
    a7a = word[6]
    a8a = word[7]
    a9a = word[8]
    a10a = word[9]
    a11a = word[10]
    a12a = word[11]
    a13a = word[12]
    a14a = word[13]
    a15a = word[14]
    lis = [a1a, a2a, a3a, a4a, a5a, a6a, a7a, a8a, a9a, a10a, a11a, a12a, a13a, a14a, a15a]

if length == 16:
    s = '_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _'
    a1a = word[0]
    a2a = word[1]
    a3a = word[2]
    a4a = word[3]
    a5a = word[4]
    a6a = word[5]
    a7a = word[6]
    a8a = word[7]
    a9a = word[8]
    a10a = word[9]
    a11a = word[10]
    a12a = word[11]
    a13a = word[12]
    a14a = word[13]
    a15a = word[14]
    a16a = word[15]
    lis = [a1a, a2a, a3a, a4a, a5a, a6a, a7a, a8a, a9a, a10a, a11a, a12a, a13a, a14a, a15a, a16a]

if length == 17:
    s = '_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _'
    a1a = word[0]
    a2a = word[1]
    a3a = word[2]
    a4a = word[3]
    a5a = word[4]
    a6a = word[5]
    a7a = word[6]
    a8a = word[7]
    a9a = word[8]
    a10a = word[9]
    a11a = word[10]
    a12a = word[11]
    a13a = word[12]
    a14a = word[13]
    a15a = word[14]
    a16a = word[15]
    a17a = word[16]
    lis = [a1a, a2a, a3a, a4a, a5a, a6a, a7a, a8a, a9a, a10a, a11a, a12a, a13a, a14a, a15a, a16a, a17a]








while hangman != hangman7 or s_space != word:

    print """



    """
    print hangman
    print s


    guess = str(raw_input('Enter a letter:'))

    if guess20 == guess:
        guess21 = guess
    if guess19 == guess:
        guess20 = guess
    if guess18 == guess:
        guess19 = guess
    if guess17 == guess:
        guess18 = guess
    if guess16 == guess:
        guess17 = guess
    if guess15 == guess:
        guess16 = guess
    if guess14 == guess:
        guess15 = guess
    if guess13 == guess:
        guess14 = guess
    if guess12 == guess:
        guess13 = guess
    if guess11 == guess:
        guess12 = guess
    if guess10 == guess:
        guess11 = guess
    if guess9 == guess:
        guess10 = guess
    if guess8 == guess:
        guess9 = guess
    if guess7 == guess:
        guess8 = guess
    if guess6 == guess:
        guess7 = guess
    if guess5 == guess:
        guess6 = guess
    if guess4 == guess:
        guess5 = guess
    if guess3 == guess:
        guess4 = guess
    if guess2 == guess:
        guess3 = guess
    if guess == guess:
        guess2 = guess
        li = [guess, guess2, guess3, guess4, guess5, guess6, guess7, guess8, guess9, guess10, guess11, guess12, guess13, guess14, guess15, guess16, guess17, guess18, guess19, guess20, guess21]



    if guess.isalpha():




        if not guess in lis:
            print 'Try again'
            inc = guess
            if hangman == hangman6:
                hangman = hangman7
                incorrect = inc in li
                rong = []
                rong.append(incorrect)
                print s
                print 'incorrect:'
                print rong
                print hangman7
                sys.exit(" ")
            elif hangman == hangman5:
                hangman = hangman6
                incorrect = inc in li
                rong = []
                rong.append(incorrect)
                print s
                print 'incorrect:'
                print rong
            elif hangman == hangman4:
                hangman = hangman5
                incorrect = inc in li
                rong = []
                rong.append(incorrect)
                print s
                print 'incorrect:'
                print rong
            elif hangman == hangman3:
                hangman = hangman4
                incorrect = inc in li
                rong = []
                rong.append(incorrect)
                print s
                print 'incorrect:'
                print rong
            elif hangman == hangman2:
                hangman = hangman3
                incorrect = inc in li
                rong = []
                rong.append(incorrect)
                print s
                print 'incorrect:'
                print rong
            elif hangman == hangman1:
                hangman = hangman2
                incorrect = inc in li
                rong = []
                rong.append(incorrect)
                print s
                print 'incorrect:'
                print rong
            elif hangman == hangman0:
                hangman = hangman1
                incorrect = inc in li
                rong = []
                rong.append(incorrect)
                print s
                print 'incorrect:'
                print rong

            else:
                gue = 'hi'






        if guess in lis:
            if guess == a1a:
                correct = a1a
                t = list(s)
                t[0] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")


            elif guess == a2a:
                correct = a2a
                t = list(s)
                t[2] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print hangman
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")


            elif guess == a3a:
                correct = a3a
                t = list(s)
                t[4] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")


            elif guess == a4a:
                correct = a4a
                t = list(s)
                t[6] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")


            elif guess == a5a:
                correct = a5a
                t = list(s)
                t[8] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")


            elif guess == a6a:
                correct = a6a
                t = list(s)
                t[10] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")

            elif guess == a7a:
                correct = a7a
                t = list(s)
                t[12] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")

            elif guess == a8a:
                correct = a8a
                t = list(s)
                t[14] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")

            elif guess == a9a:
                correct = a9a
                t = list(s)
                t[16] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")

            elif guess == a10a:
                correct = a10a
                t = list(s)
                t[18] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")

            elif guess == a11a:
                correct = a11a
                t = list(s)
                t[20] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")

            elif guess == a12a:
                correct = a12a
                t = list(s)
                t[22] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")

            elif guess == a13a:
                correct = a13a
                t = list(s)
                t[24] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")

            elif guess == a14a:
                correct = a14a
                t = list(s)
                t[26] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")

            elif guess == a15a:
                correct = a15a
                t = list(s)
                t[28] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")

            elif guess == a16a:
                correct = a16a
                t = list(s)
                t[30] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")

            elif guess == a17a:
                correct = a17a
                t = list(s)
                t[32] = guess
                s = "".join(t)
                print guess
                s_0 = s.replace(" ","")

            print hangman
            print s
            if s_0 == word:
                print s_0
                print 'You Won!'
                print googe
                import time
                time.sleep(3)
                print ' This program was written using Python, by Slass33'
                print comps
                break
                co = raw_input('Do you want to play again?(yes/no):')
                if co == 'yes':
                    print """

                    """
                elif co == 'no':
                    sys.exit

                else:
                    co = raw_input('Do you want to play again?(yes/no):')



sys.exit
```

So, it is working fine (set aside, a few minor glitches). But my problem is, that I want it to display all the previous incorrect guesses under the `rong` list, but it isn't working. Any ideas how? This main part is:

```
if not guess in lis:
    print 'Try again'
    inc = guess
    if hangman == hangman6:
        hangman = hangman7
        incorrect = inc in li
        rong = []
        rong.append(incorrect)
        print s
        print 'incorrect:'
        print rong
        print hangman7
        sys.exit(" ")
    elif hangman == hangman5:
        hangman = hangman6
        incorrect = inc in li
        rong = []
        rong.append(incorrect)
        print s
        print 'incorrect:'
        print rong
    elif hangman == hangman4:
        hangman = hangman5
        incorrect = inc in li
        rong = []
        rong.append(incorrect)
        print s
        print 'incorrect:'
        print rong
    elif hangman == hangman3:
        hangman = hangman4
        incorrect = inc in li
        rong = []
        rong.append(incorrect)
        print s
        print 'incorrect:'
        print rong
    elif hangman == hangman2:
        hangman = hangman3
        incorrect = inc in li
        rong = []
        rong.append(incorrect)
        print s
        print 'incorrect:'
        print rong
    elif hangman == hangman1:
        hangman = hangman2
        incorrect = inc in li
        rong = []
        rong.append(incorrect)
        print s
        print 'incorrect:'
        print rong
    elif hangman == hangman0:
        hangman = hangman1
        incorrect = inc in li
        rong = []
        rong.append(incorrect)
        print s
        print 'incorrect:'
        print rong
```

So basically, if the guess `!=` any index of the word, display a version of the hangman `string`, and the rest is known. Any `var` with `hangman` in it is a display.
Can anyone fix this for me, or improve this code?

P.S. Ignore the fact that `animals[ ]` only has `'Swan'`. If you don't know what I'm saying, ignore this.

Comment: Your code is very repetitious. There is no reason to have so many variable (one for each character of each possible length of a word). Use lists! Do things like s = '-'*length and lis = list(word). That alone will eliminate dozens of lines of code and variables and enable you to write a main loop without a proliferation of cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not reassign an empty list to `rong` inside the `if...elif` block, this causes any previous values in `rong` list to go away.

You should just initialize `rong` before the game starts (maybe there is a while or for loop you didn't include that is the main part of the game) , you should initialize `rong` to `[]` there and only append to that list in the if blocks.

Example -

```
 rong = []
 while <condition>: #Game loop?
 .
 .
 .
 if not guess in lis:
     .
     .
     if hangman == hangman6:
         .
         #rong = [] #Do not do this.
         rong.append(incorrect) #Just append to 'rong' .
```